# Calling destructor by object pointer

Tags: c++, vtable, virtual-destructor

Can you please explain why the following code does not crash and how it is handled not to.

```
class Base
{
public:
    Base() {cout << "Base constr" << endl;}
    virtual void func() {cout << "Base func()" << endl;}
    virtual ~Base() {cout << "Base destr" << endl;}
};

class Layer1 : public Base
{
public:
    Layer1() {cout << "Layer1 constr" << endl;}
    virtual void func() {cout << "Layer1 func()" << endl;}
    virtual ~Layer1() {cout << "Layer1 destr" << endl;}
};

class Layer2 : public Layer1
{
public:
    Layer2() {cout << "Layer2 constr" << endl;}
    virtual void func() {cout << "Layer2 func()" << endl;}
    ~Layer2() {cout << "Layer2 destr" << endl;}
};

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    Layer2 * l2ptr = (Layer2 *) new Base;
    l2ptr->func();
    delete l2ptr;

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Base constr
Base func()
Base destr
```

I mean at the point where delete l2ptr is called. From the first look it seems that `Layer2` destructor should be called, but no `Layer2` object has been created. Also, `Layer2` destructor is not `virtual`. When I make it virtual the output is the same. Why?
And the next question: what issues and considerations there are on accesing parent class object by it's child class pointer?

EDIT:
If I change `Layer2` class to this

```
class Layer2 : public Layer1
{
public:
    Layer2() {cout << "Layer2 constr" << endl;}
    virtual void func() {cout << "Layer2 func()" << endl;}
    void func2() {cout << "Layer2 func2()" << endl;}
    virtual ~Layer2() {cout << "Layer2 destr" << endl;}
};
```

And `main()` like this:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    Layer2 * l2ptr = (Layer2 *) new Base;
    l2ptr->func();
    l2ptr->func2();
    delete l2ptr;

    return 0;
}
```

It still works and the output is:

```
Base constr
Base func()
Layer2 func2()
Base destr
```

Again, why?

Comment: Your code has undefined behaviour. That means that anything can happen, and you are in deed observing that something is happening.

Comment: You have UB little after `(Layer2 *) new Base`...

Comment: http://blog.llvm.org/2016/04/undefined-behavior-is-magic.html

Comment: In your first example `Layer2`'s destructor *is* virtual; it inherits the virtual-ness from `Layer1` and `Base`.

Answer (score 4):

Your code has undefined behavior, so almost any question about why it does anything is meaningless and unanswerable. To the extent it does any particular thing at all, it's basically just luck.

You have things basically backwards of what you probably intended (or of what you should have intended in any case), which would have a `main` something on this order:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    Base *bptr = new Layer2;
    bptr->func();       

    Layer2 *l2ptr = dynamic_cast<Layer2 *>(bptr);

    if (l2ptr)
        l2ptr->func2();

    delete bptr;
}
```

Here we use a `pointer to Base` to refer to an object of type `Layer2`, rather than vice versa. Since Layer2 is derived from `Base`, this is allowed and the behavior is meaningful.

That lets us talk about the details of why it does what it does.

The destructor not being marked `virtual` in `Layer2` is basically irrelevant: since it's marked `virtual` in a base class, it remains `virtual` in all derived classes:

C++ standard, §[class.virtual]/2:

> If a virtual member function vf is declared in a class Base and in a class Derived, derived directly or indirectly from Base, a member function vf with the same name, parameter-type-list (8.3.5), cv-qualification, and ref-qualifier (or absence of same) as Base::vf is declared, then Derived::vf is also virtual (whether or not it is so declared) and it *overrides* <sup>111</sup> Base::vf.

C++ standard, §[class.virtual]/6:

> Even though destructors are not inherited, a destructor in a derived class overrides a base class destructor declared virtual;

Comment: That vice versa was intended to be as is in my post. But your assumption and suggested code is appreciated. And about virtual-ness inheritance from base: where I can find that information in C++ reference?

Answer (score 0):

Your code has undefined behaviour as has been pointed out - for example when you access a `Base` object via a pointer to `Layer2`.

Undefined behaviour includes appearing to work (and indeed anything else). In this case it happens that the layout of the objects is sufficiently similar that nothing goes too badly wrong. The vtable pointers are in the same place; calls to virtual functions correctly go to the `Base` versions, because the object is a `Base` and contains a pointer to the `Base` vtable. Non-virtual functions go to the type you told the compiler the object was.

(Implementations don't have to use a vtable, but they usually do.)

But it's all still undefined behaviour; don't do this, and most definitely don't rely on it.

Comment: Thank you, I got it. I truly do not trying to make out with UB, but I am interested "why". Two more question: (1) but why Layer2 and Layer1 destructors are not called on delete l2ptr? (2) Now how delete and generally C++ works when it comes to calling destructors (btw, I know that delete is a lib function that freeing heap mamory)?

Comment: The destructors are all virtual; when you do `delete l2ptr` it looks in the vtable, finds the `Base` destructor, and calls it. If you had a real `Layer2` object the vtable would point to its destructor, which would then call its base destructors.

Comment: "The destructors are all virtual" what do you mean? Always? When I declare Layer2 as virtual it is correct: destructor gets called by resolving vtable dispatch. But when I do not declare it as virtual, it is statically resolveable. But in this case it does not work

Comment: All your destructors are virtual. Layer2's destructor is virtual in all these cases, regardless of whether you explicitly declare it that way. If a base class has a virtual destructor, the destructors of all derived classes are automatically virtual. (As Jerry explains in his answer, and I mentioned in my comment on your question.)

Comment: I first saw your comment and after that Jerry answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Correct me if I'm wrong but you never construct an object of either `Layer2` or `Layer1`; only a `Base` object which you casts (in C style, mind you, not C++) to a pointer to a `Layer2` type. That is to say, `func2` won't be available to the object your pointer points to, but the compiler accepts it because it only checkes the static type of your pointer.